# Regex - Echoing the first character of a string

Tags: php, regex

I try to echo the first letter of "SiteName", I am having a bit of difficulties, the expression below returns "1" instead of "S".

```
// $sitename = $GLOBALS["AL_CFG"]["siteName"];

$sitename = "SiteName.com";
$sitename1 = preg_match("/.{0,1}/", $sitename);
echo $sitename1;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's because [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) returns an integer.  Read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only trying to capture the first character in a string, then you do not need to use a regular expression.

```
$sitename = "SiteName.com";
$letter = substr($sitename, 0, 1);
echo $letter; // prints "S"
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) returns a value indicating whether the match succeeded or not, and *not* the actual match itself. To access the matches, you need to specify the third argument, an array, in which you would like to have the matches stored:

```
$sitename1 = preg_match("/.{0,1}/", $sitename, $matches);
print_r($matches);
echo $matches[0]; // => 'S'
```

Anyway, if you're just trying to get the first character of a given string, **you don't need to use regex at all**; you can simply access the string as a character array:

From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr):

> Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using square array brackets, as in `$str[42]`. Think of a string as an array of characters for this purpose. The functions [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) and [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/substr_replace) can be used when you want to extract or replace more than 1 character.

So to get the first charcter from `$sitename`, you would write:

```
echo $sitename[0]; // => 'S'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I suspected I was missing an action!

Comment: @user3371049: Happens. Glad to have helped!